# Getting an UNDEFINED value from services in angular13

Tags: angular, service

**Iam using a POST method function in service and calling the function in sendingcomponent and saving the response in service variable and sending the variable to receivingcomponent and assigning the data to another variable but getting an undefined value i receivingcomponent **

sending.component.ts

```
import{sharedservice}....
constructor(private services:sharedservice)
ngOnInit(){
this.formvalue()
}
this.formvalue(){
this.services.getdata(this.form.value)
}
```

shared.services.ts

```
import{Httpclient}....
@Injectable()
dataofservice:any;
constructor(private http:httpClient)
this.getdata(data:any){
this.http.post('http://localhost:3002/data')
.subscribe(res =>{
this.dataofservice= res   
console.log(this.dataofservice) -->(here I am getting the value)
})
}
```

receiving.component.ts

```
import{sharedservice}....
constructor(private services:sharedservice)
datatostore:any;
ngOnInit(){
this.datatostore = this.services.dataofservice  
console.log(this.datatostore)-->(here I am getting value as UNDEFINED)
}
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend subscribing in the service, let the service return the `observable`. Also, based on your approach, you could use a `subject` or similar in order to notify your `receiving` component once your reach it.

```js
import{Httpclient}....
@Injectable()
export class YourService {
   private dataofservice = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  
   constructor(private http: httpClient)
   
   this.getdata(data: any): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:3002/data').pipe(
         tap(response => this.dataofservice.next(response))
      );
   })

   getDataOfService(): Observable<any> {
      return this.dataofservice.asObservable();
   }
}
```

**sending component**

```js
constructor(private services:sharedservice) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.formvalue()
}

formvalue() {
  this.services.getdata(this.form.value)
   .subscribe(console.log); // your data is here
}
```

**receiving component**

```js
...
 constructor(private services:sharedservice) {}
   
  ngOnInit() {
    this.services.getDataOfService(data)
     .subscribe((response) => console.log(response)) // and here as well
  }
```

Comment: I am still getting the value as undefined

Comment: @Rohith_29, I modified the service, look if using `BehaviorSubject` solves your problem, otherwise, I would suggest adding a reproducible example on Stackblitz

Comment: @Andres2141, I found that using `setTimeout`  giving the value. If there is any alternate for using `setTimeout` let me know. Your code is working I am getting undefined because I am routing from `sending component` to `Receiving component`  so there isn't enough time to get data that's why. **Thanks for your help bro** It helps me a lot